# Scrape text from a website using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I found this [article](http://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/how-to-scrape-title-and-header-h1-from-web-pages-using-excel-vba/) explaining how to scrape certain tags from a website using Excel VBA.

The code below gets the content from the first `<p>` tag that it finds:

```
Sub get_title_header()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = Cells(i, 1)

    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = True

    While wb.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'HTML document
    Set doc = wb.document

    Cells(i, 2) = doc.title

    On Error GoTo err_clear
    Cells(i, 3) = doc.GetElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText
    err_clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

End Sub
```

I'd like to make the scraper get all the content that is within a `<p>` tag on a webpage. So I guess a `foreach` functionality of some kind is missing.

How can the content from multiple `<p>` tags be collected?

**UPDATE**
The working code!

```
Sub get_title_header()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = Cells(i, 1)

    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = True

    While wb.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'HTML document
    Set doc = wb.document

    Cells(i, 2) = doc.Title

    On Error GoTo err_clear

    Dim el As Object
    For Each el In doc.GetElementsByTagName("p")

        counter = counter + 1
        Cells(i, counter + 2).Value = Cells(counter + 1).Value & el.innerText

    Next el
    counter = 0

    err_clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there!  `doc.GetElementsByTagName("p")` returns a collection of `HTMLParagraphElement` objects of which you accessed the first entry using `doc.GetElementsByTagName("p")(0)`.  As you allude to, a `For Each` loop would let you access each in turn:

```
Sub get_title_header()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
sURL = Cells(i, 1)

wb.navigate sURL
wb.Visible = True

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

'HTML document
Set doc = wb.document

Cells(i, 2) = doc.Title

On Error GoTo err_clear

Dim el As Object
For Each el In doc.GetElementsByTagName("p")
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & el.innerText
Next el

err_clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
wb.Quit
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks, tried your code but it won't return anything.. Is something missing? Thanks again!

Comment: @RobbertT I've copied in the code i tested.  It'sa modified version of your code which doesn't have any of the worksheet references for simplicity.  Also, all the output goes to the immediate window (`Ctrl+G`).  This worked perfectly on my PC and shouldn't be to hard to modify as neccessary for your purposes

Comment: Awesome, that worked! however still trying to figure out how to make it work with the urls in column a and the p content in column b of a excel sheet.. You could download the example on the bottom of the article that i mentioned, to see what i mean. Thanks

Comment: @RobbertT Again, you were almost there.  This just loops through each `<p>` tag and concatenates the text to the string that is already in column 3

Comment: This is so amazingly cool, i had no idea such a thing was possible with Excel. Awesome, works like a charm. One more request; is it possible to put the content of every <p> found in a seperate cell (column) on the same row? Thaanks!

Comment: @RobbertT Of course, try including a counter inside the `For Each` loop and using that to increment the column that you write `el.innerText` to.

Comment: Hi, yes.. i figured it should be inside the for each loop. I did some searching on Google and i guess that a `+ 1` could do that correct? Should this be placed in the line `Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & el.innerText` ?

Comment: @RobbertT Yeah, you'd want to use something like `counter = counter + 1` in the `For Each` loop then use `counter` to as the column argument to the `Cells` property i.e. `Cells(i, counter + 2).Value`.  Remember to reset the counter back to 0 before you enter the `For Each` loop each time or it'll contain the last column of the previous URL.  Post your modified code back into the question if you get stuck and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: Cool, see my working code in my question now! Thanks! Could you confirm this is all correct? EDIT: See my edited question, something goes wrong.. Might be the counter reset?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get the content of the webpage in plain text this code is more concise

```
Function WEBSITE_TEXT(Destination As String) As String
' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
' Draws on the stackoverflow answer at bit.ly/parseXML
Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60

    ' Check and clean inputs
    On Error GoTo exitRoute

    If Destination = "" Then
      WEBSITE_TEXT = ""
     Exit Function
    End If

    ' Read the XML data from the Google Maps API
    Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
    myRequest.Open "GET", Destination, False
    myRequest.send

    ' Parse HTML content
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim text As String
    html.body.innerHTML = myRequest.responseText

    ' Return the website content
    text = html.body.innerText
    If Not html Is Nothing Then WEBSITE_TEXT = text
exitRoute:
    ' Tidy up
    text = ""
    Set myRequest = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I get a "User defined type not defined" error for this line of code:  Dim html As HTMLDocument

Comment: Ah:  In addition to a reference to the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library, you also have to add a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library