# ms excel extracting information from jira [atlassian]

Tags: excel, jira, vba

I need to extract data from a a jira web page and put it into excel. Are there any plugins or examples that I could use to get me going?. i was thinking of coding a vba script but want to see what other options I can use. i know that jira has a restful api that I could use.

Comment: I've never tried using JIRA before, but in VBA you can parse the HTML and identify tags and properties.  There's an example here.... http://stackoverflow.com/q/29821918/4437159

Answer (score 0):

With **JExcel** add-on, you can import/export JIRA data from/to Excel.

It is also possible to use Ctrl C + Ctrl V for importing and exporting.
It totally feels like an Excel in JIRA. And Its completely free!

You can download it from the Marketplace: 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.moresimp.jexcel