# Importing data from multiple webpages using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I have 2 URL's that I want to scrape the entire data off the landing page into one column in excel in a worksheet. URL's are;
    URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/257/hogan-lovells
    URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3635/king-spalding

When I do it manually in excel via "data/from web" I can collect the data but when I try using VBA no data is returned. I am wanting a separate worksheet for each URL in a work book. I am then wanting to add more URL's to the list so that a programme can loop through them. Please can any one help? Thanks in advance.

The VBA code is below:

```
    Sub adds()
    For x = 1 To 5
    Worksheets("chambers").Select
    Worksheets("chambers").Activate
    mystr = "URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/257/hogan-     lovells"
    mystr = Cells(x, 1)
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr,        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
   'CommandType = 0
   .Name = "hogan-lovells"
   .FieldNames = True
   .RowNumbers = False
   .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
   .PreserveFormatting = True
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
   .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
   .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
   .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
   Next x
   End Sub
```

These are the five URLs in `Cells(x, 1)` I am trying to grab with this code:

```
URL;chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/257/hogan-lovells 
URL;chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3635/king-spalding 
URL;chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3636/kirkland-ellis 
URL;chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3689/latham-watkins 
URL;chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/255/linklaters
```

Comment: `...but when I try using VBA no data is returned.` Please update the post and include the VBA code you have used to extract data from these websites. Without this code we cannot help you debugging it (or tell why it isn't working).

Comment: I have updated my post now with the vba code. Thank you.

Comment: The reason why I want to understand the VBA solution is so that when the links change every 3 months I can quickly change them from a list already defined

Comment: With the line `myStr = "URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/257/hogan-     lovells"` you are setting the URL to something which cannot work (with all the spaces in between). But then you are changing `myStr` immediately in the next line of code again to `mystr = Cells(x, 1)`. This translates to `mystr = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value`. So, the connections can only work if the URL given in these cells is correct. Hence, please update your post with the content of these five cells.

Comment: BTW: I just tried to grab the website / URL you posted as an example and found out that it cannot be imported using `QueryTables`. So, you'll have to look for new ways to scrape this website or revert over to a website which can be imported using `QueryTables`.

Comment: Hi. Here are all of the 5 urls that require to be used:                                           URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/257/hogan-lovells
URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3635/king-spalding
URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3636/kirkland-ellis
URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/3689/latham-watkins
URL;http://www.chambersandpartners.com/Global/firm/255/linklaters

Comment: The url has different numbers and firm names at the end

Comment: Just as I commented above: these URLs cannot be imported using QueryTables. You'll have to change your code to use different web-scraping strategy. This one works for your sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821918/scrape-text-from-website-using-excel-vba I tested it.

Comment: Thanks Ralph for your support and time

Comment: @ChrisMoore could you please show an example output (i. e. manually populated) you want to be scraped into the column in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If manually adding your data with the default Excel Webquery works, you can use VBA to simply refresh your queries.

This is the easiest way of doing automated Queries if you do not need dynamic URL handling or parsing.

Simply create all of your connections, then use Macro Recording to record your refreshes, then tweak the resulting VBA.

> You can find all of your active connections under the Data tab -> Connections